# Как обработать cookie-файл приходящий в ответ вместе с json-массивом со стороннего сервера?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, cookie

Есть следующий код:

```
import requests, json
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from time import sleep
import sys


if sys.version_info < (3,):
    def u(x):
        try:
            return x.encode("utf8")
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            return x
else:
    def u(x):
        if type(x) == type(b''):
            return x.decode('utf8')
        else:
            return x


authURL =  'https://xxx.amocrm.ru/private/api/auth.php?type=json'
auth = {
    'USER_LOGIN':'',
    'USER_HASH':'',
}

jsonAuth = json.dumps(auth, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')

try:
    authrequest = requests.post(authURL, jsonAuth)

    if authrequest.status_code != 200 or authrequest.json().get("error", False):
        print('Произошла ошибка при обращении к серверу')
        print('Ошибка: {}'.format(authrequest.json()['response']['error']))
    else:
        print('Авторизация {}'.format(authrequest.json()['response']['auth']))
        #print('Ответ {}'.format(authrequest.json()))

except request.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print('Connection error')
except:
    print('Unknow error')
```

Этот код, в ответ на запрос, при успешной авторизации, кроме тела ответа возвращается cookie файл, содержащий ключ сессии, аналогично работе с WEB-браузером. При дальнейших запросах к API-методам нужно обратно передавать полученные cookie. Время жизни сессии - 15 минут.

Вопрос в следующем, как этот cookie файл обработать, и как в дальнейшем передавать его при запросе?

Comment: Смотрели в response header у ответа?

Comment: Уже разобрался. `session = requests.Session()` `authrequest = session.post(authURL, jsonAuth)` `cookies = session.cookies` `result = requests.get(dealsURL, cookies = cookies)` , единственное, что непонятно, ответ от сервера не содержит кода, то есть проверку на 200, 204, error = False, не проходит, но ответ содержит все нужные параметры. А вообще, API у амки кривое до нельзя. Большинство моментов похоже придётся реализовывать через костыли.

Comment: `ответ от сервера не содержит кода` быть не может, что `result.status_code` ничего не возвращает ) раз сами разобрались, добавьте это в ответ :)

Comment: Странно, `result.status_code` возвращает '204', но проверку почему-то не проходит.
Может дело в условии? `if result.status_code != 200 or result.status_code != 204 or result.json().get("error", False):`

Comment: вроде бы условие правильное... нужно вам у себя потестить :) кст, а почему бы вам не поменять тогда проверка на первую цифру? Например `if not str(result.status_code).startswith("2") or "error" in result.json():`

Comment: И действительно, так работает. Попробую поковыряться, всё же очень странно, что он не захотел работать с обычным условием.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, в python организация обработки и отправки в ответ cookie файла, происходит примерно следующим образом:

Открывается сессия для работы с cookie: `session = requests.Session()`

Формируется тело запроса: `jsonAuth = json.dumps(auth, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')`

Запрос посылается в сессии: `authrequest = session.post(authURL, jsonAuth)`

Далее обрабатываются файлы cookies: `cookies = session.cookies`

Следующие запросы должны содержать внутри переменную, хранящую cookies: `result = requests.get(dealsURL, cookies = cookies)`

Comment: Ещё момент, `requests.get`, может быть изменён на `requests.post`, даже если по факту используется метод get. Там просто неявно он будет указан в теле самого запроса. С этим тоже мучался, ибо у Яндекса API работает посредством неявного указания метода, а у амки нужно явно указать метод.